# Using JavaScript classes inside TypeScript Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to access some JavaScript classes (defined in `.js` files) in my Angular TypeScript component, however I'm getting the following error when building my project:

```
error TS5055: Cannot write file '/Users/Aleksander/Development/Web/tradeapp/src/js/exchanges/exchange.js' because it would overwrite input file.
Adding a tsconfig.json file will help organize projects that contain both TypeScript and JavaScript files. Learn more at https://aka.ms/tsconfig.
```

I have a `tsconfig.json` file in my root directory (`/Users/Aleksander/Development/tradeapp/`), where I've set `"allowJs": true` and `"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc"` (as generated by the CLI).

If I remove the `"allowJs": true` flag and put all my JavaScript files in the root `/tradeapp/src/` directory, it works. However I'd love to separate this into its own directory.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: See: [Why am I getting the error TS5055: Cannot write file 'xxx.js' because it would overwrite input file. when using JavaScript files?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-am-i-getting-the-error-ts5055-cannot-write-file-xxxjs-because-it-would-overwrite-input-file-when-using-javascript-files)

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez thanks, but like I mentioned I already have the `outDir` set. Perhaps I've done it wrong, would you mind elaborating what else I could do?